# Include Javascript function from another file but retain the function scope

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to call a function from a seperate Javascript file as if it was part of the "main" Javascript file **without** using something like require.js?

The issue i have here is that message and innerFunction are undefined in my method in file2.

*html*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/example/file2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/example/file1.js"></script>
```

*File1.js*

```
(function() {

    // self invoking function 
    function doSomething() {
            var message = "hello world";

            // declared in file2.js
            MyGlobal.sayMessage();

            return;
            function innerFunction() { ... }


    }
}());
```

*File 2*

```
var MyGlobal = {};
(function() {

    // self invoking function 
    MyGlobal.sayMessage = function() {

        // message and function from file 1 as if it were just part of the same file
        console.log(message);
        innerFunction();

    }

}());
```

---

I may be asking the impossible but who knows. I have already come up with this method, but it doesn't feel right.

**My attempt**

*File1.js*

```
(function() {

    // self invoking function 
    function doSomething() {
            var message = "hello world";       
            var scope = {
                message: message,
                innerFunction: innerFunction
            };

            // pass "scope"
            MyGlobal.sayMessage(scope);

            return;
            function innerFunction() { ... }


    }
}());
```

*File2.js*

```
var MyGlobal = {};
(function() {

    // self invoking function 
    MyGlobal.sayMessage = function(scope) {

        // message and function from file 1 as if it were just part of the same file
        console.log(scope.message);
        scope.innerFunction();

    }

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would redefine `sayMessage` to

```
MyGlobal.sayMessage = function(message, callback)
```

Unless you declare `message` and `innerFunction` outside IIFE and move it to global scope, you don't have a choice.